# Grav CMS page names

Tags: content-management-system, grav

I have been experimenting with [Grav](http://getgrav.org) for a few days now and find it a real breath of fresh air for someone who has only ever used WordPress.  However, there is one thing that bothers me.  The folder structure driven flat file page hierarchy used by Grav can easily end up with a folder structure like the one below

```
01.home
 |
 --- default.en.md
     |
     01.sub-page-1
                 |
                  --- default.en.md
     |
     02.sub-page-2
                 |
                  --- default.en.md
```

There in lies the problem. I prefer to edit my markdown in Visual Studio Code via SFTP, not in the Grav Admin panel.  However, that means that I can end up with multiple default.en.md files open at the same time and that is a disaster waiting to happen.  Is it possible to rename the markdown files to something more logical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually.

By default, grav pulls the template type from the markdown file's name. However, you can override this behavior by setting the `template` variable in your page's YAML header. So we could easily have something like:

```
01.home
 |
 --- homepage.en.md
     |
     01.sub-page-1
                 |
                  --- home.subpage1.en.md
```

If we simply have a header of

```
---
title: blah
template: default
...
---
```

Comment: So in other words, the page name can be changed just so long as you also specify a template in the page frontmatter?

Comment: @DroidOS yes, the template variable will override the file name.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the markdown file specifies which template to use. So in your example, all the pages in each subfolder will use `default.html.twig` located in `templates/THEME_IN_USE/` folder.

I presume you've downloaded the basic template from Grav's official page. In that case, the default template is Antimatter. You can see that in *themes/anitmatter* there's a file called *default.html.twig*, so this template is applied. However, if you would set the theme in *user/config/system.yaml* to let's say my-theme (instead of Antimatter), you could define your own default.html.twig (your own template).

So to answer your question, you could create your own template for each page, or better still a template for similar pages (like blog posts). You could end up with something like this then.

```
pages
  01.home
   |
   --- default.en.md
       |
       01.blog-post
                   |
                    --- blog.en.md
       |
       02.contact
                   |
                    --- contact.en.md
themes
  my-theme
   |
    ...

    templates
        --- default.html.twig
        --- blog.html.twig
        --- contact.html.twig
```